# How do I know what version of SQL Server Express my database is in?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sql-server-express

A year ago or so I started to develop an app in Visual Studio 2013. The database was in the SQL Server Express edition.

I'm just getting back to it now. I've upgraded VS to 2015 Community edition and wanted to use the DB. But I can't open it. The error I am receiving is:

> The Data Source value in the connection string specifies an instance of SQL Server that is not installed. To resolve this issue, you can either choose to install the matching instance of SQL Server or modify the Data Source value in the connection string.

I'm trying to figure out what version the old db is in so I can install the proper version or change the connection string. How do I find out the version of SQL Server Express the database is in?

Comment: Have you tried looking at Uninstall Programs?

Comment: Query the db `select @@version`

Comment: I can't open the db so I don't see how I can query it.

Comment: Check out this article by Remus Rusanu: http://rusanu.com/2011/04/04/how-to-determine-the-database-version-of-an-mdf-file/

Comment: I found that provided my localDb server version was greater/larger than the version of the localDb mdf I was trying to open, VS 2015 would do an upgrade. Just dbl-click the mdf file after sticking in a project. Also it pays to get used to using the command line tool 'SqlLocalDb'. Just type in "SqlLocalDb info" to see what versions of local db (v11.0, ProjectsV12, ProjectsV13, MSSQLLocalDB) are installed on your machine

Answer (score 5):

1) Click on **server explorer** and found your database

2) right click on the database of your solution

3) on the menu click for a new query

4) on the new query type: `select @@version`

5) read for your db version