# Query to get average of sum column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I have a table with a `Date` column I want to group in 5 minutes intervals, and the sum of `Volume` for each interval. I also want the average of this sum column - how do I do it?

```
SELECT Ticker,
       Date,
       Volume
FROM   share
WHERE  Ticker = 'divya'
```

Here's my attempt, except I don't want the average volume, I want the average value for the sum of the volume:

```
SELECT Ticker,
       MIN(Date)   AS Time,
       SUM(Volume) AS SumVolume,
       AVG(Volume) AS AverageSumVolume
FROM   share
WHERE  Ticker = 'divya'
GROUP  BY (DATEPART(MINUTE, Date) / 5), Ticker
```

Another attempt:

```
select Ticker, 
       MIN(Date)as Time,  
       (select top 1 [Open] from share where ticker = 'divya' ) as OpenValue,--       need first value of 5 mins data
       Max(High) as Max, 
       Min(low) as Low,
       (select top 1 [Close] from share where ticker = 'divya') as Closevalue,--       need last value of 5 mins data
       sum(Volume) as SumVolume,
       avg(SumVolume) as SumAverageVolume,-- average of SumVolume
       (select top 1 [Open Interest] from share where ticker = 'divya') as OpenInterest
from share where Ticker = 'divya' 
GROUP BY (DATEPART(MINUTE, Date)/5 ),Ticker
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Are you really running 3 different versions of SQL-Server? which one do you really have? Also, in the future, please post the data into the question instead of in an image

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186375/how-do-i-know-what-version-of-sql-server-express-my-database-is-in) would at least help you determine your SQL Server version.

Comment: @Chandan please check your version number and remove the tags that don't belong there. Also,  you can edit your question to put your two queries in there - the ones which you put into the comment. Please post what you're getting in the second set of results.

Comment: @Chandan Please add the data you commented, to the question with proper formatting.

Comment: @Chandan I have attempted to rewrite your question to make it more understandable - feel free to revert if you think I have misunderstood you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    Ticker
    ,DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0,Date)/5 * 5, 0)
    , SUM(Volume) AS SumVolume
    , AVG(Volume) AS AverageSumVolume 
FROM share 
WHERE Ticker = 'divya' 
GROUP BY Ticker, DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0,Date)/5 * 5, 0)
```

Please read the following so that you can understand what is going on:

> DATEADD: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql
>
> DATEDIFF: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql

**UPDATE:**
This would give you what you're looking for if I understood your comment correctly.

```
SELECT
    ticker
    ,[time]
    ,SumVolume
    ,AVG(SumVolume) OVER(PARTITION BY ticker) AS AverageSumVolume 
FROM(
    SELECT 
        Ticker
        ,DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0,Date)/5 * 5, 0) AS Time
        , SUM(Volume) AS SumVolume
    FROM share 
    WHERE Ticker = 'divya' 
    GROUP BY Ticker,DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0,Date)/5 * 5, 0)
) a
GROUP BY 
    ticker
    ,[time]
    ,sumvolume
```

Comment: If you want the average of SUM, as in the previous column, then you'll need to wrap this whole thing in a sub query

Comment: can you write a query for AverageSumVolume

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'... in second group by keyword

Comment: There was an extra comma there, I removed it, also aliased sub query

Comment: ya.. but I want average of sumvolume column

Comment: its AverageSumVolume of Volume column I want from SumVolume column

Comment: Show a sample of what you're expecting to see

Comment: 230+270+170+210=880/4= 220(AverageSumVolume)

Comment: So you expect to see this 220 average in all rows?

Comment: Ok, added windowing function - check it out.

Comment: its working but now my own query not working, kindly check I updated my question

Comment: @Chandan you aren't using the windowing function, how are you getting the correct results?